# How do you write an advanced mutator method for arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, poker, mutators

I'm relatively new to programming, so this is very confusing to me. In this program, I declared and instantiated an array of 5 card EMPTY SLOTS (from a program called Card.java in which all the cards are complete). This is my constructor method:

```
 public BasicPlayer()
 {
    myHand = new Card[5];
 }
```

Then I'm supposed to declare an advanced mutator and accessor method for arrays (the getter and setter I assume), which is where I am stuck. For the accessor method, I am supposed to get a card from the players hand:

```
   public Card getCard()
   {
     card tempCard = myHand [numberDealt];
     numberDealt ++;
     return tempCard;
   }
```

but then for the mutator method, I am supposed to set a SINGULAR CARD into the player's hand (I will create a loop in a different class setting more cards into the hand, but for now, I just need one). This is where I am stuck. What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be something as simple as this.

```
   // setters typically don't return anything.
   // and idx must satisfy 0 <= idx < myHand.length
   public void setCard(int idx, Card card) {
     myHand[idx] = card;
   }
```

However, I noticed in your other method

```
   public Card getCard() {
     Card tempCard = myHand [numberDealt];
     numberDealt ++;
     return tempCard;
   }
```

Be careful with the numberDealt increment.  If it goes beyond 4 you will throw
an indexed based Exception for exceeding the array size.  How you handle this is
up to you.

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helped! I have one more question, sorry--  so does that mean idx should replace numberDealt in the get method because the get method is taking a card from the hand? I am sorry if this seems like a dumb question.

Comment: Not necessarily.  That would be a design issue.  idx is simply the index into the array.  So the card is put in myHand at some location 0 thru 4 inclusive in your case.  How that position is chosen and the safeguards I mentioned are up to you. Does that answer the question?

Comment: Ah ok, yes that does. So then if I wanted to keep track of how many cards are in my hand, I should declare a separate int for that?

Comment: That would be one way, yes.  But if there are multiple players that could get cumbersome.  So a Hand class could be created with the cards in a Card[] array inside that class along with any other required information.

Answer (score 0):

```
more examples using enums:

package sample;
import java.util.*;
enum Rank {
        joker(new Character('*'),"Joker"),aceLow(new Character('a'),"Ace(low)"),deuce(new Character('2'),"Deuce"),trey(new Character('3'),"Trey"),four(new Character('4'),"Four"),five(new Character('5'),"Five"),six(new Character('6'),"Six"),seven(new Character('7'),"Seven"),eight(new Character('8'),"Eight"),nine(new Character('9'),"Nine"),ten(new Character('T'),"Ten"),jack(new Character('J'),"Jack"),queen(new Character('Q'),"Queen"),king(new Character('K'),"King"),aceHigh(new Character('A'),"Ace");
        Rank(final Character c,final String s) {
            this.c=c;
            this.s=s;
        }
        public static Rank fromInt(int n) {
            for(Rank r:Rank.values())
                if(r.ordinal()==n)
                    return r;
            return null;
        }
        public static Rank fromCharacter(char c) {
            for(Rank r:Rank.values())
                if(r.c==c)
                    return r;
            return null;
        }
        public static Rank[] fromCharacters(final String cards) {
            final Rank[] rank=new Rank[5];
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
                rank[i]=Rank.fromCharacter(cards.charAt(i));
            return rank;
        }
        public Character toCharacter() {
            return c;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return s;
        }
        public static String toString(final Rank[] rank) {
            String s="";
            for(Rank r:rank)
                s+=r.toCharacter();
            return s;
        }
        final Character c;
        final String s;
    }
    enum Suit {
        joker(new Character('*'),"Joker"),clubs(new Character('c'/* try character for a real dimond? */),"Club"),diamonds(new Character('d'),"Diamond"),hearts(new Character('h'),"Heart"),spades(new Character('s'),"Spade");
        Suit(final Character c,final String s) {
            this.c=c;
            this.s=s;
        }
        public static Suit fromCharacter(char c) {
            for(Suit s:Suit.values())
                if(s.c==c)
                    return s;
            return null;
        }
        public Character toCharacter() {
            return c;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return s;
        }
        public static String toString(final Suit[] suit) {
            String s_="";
            for(Suit s:suit)
                s_+=s.toCharacter();
            return s_;
        }
        public static boolean areSuited(final Suit[] suit) {
            final int n=suit.length;
            for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
                if(suit[i]!=suit[i+1])
                    return false;
            return true;
        }
        final Character c;
        final String s;
    }
    enum Card {
        joker(Rank.joker,Suit.joker),aceLowOfClubs(Rank.aceLow,Suit.clubs),aceLowOfDiamonds(Rank.aceLow,Suit.diamonds),aceLowOfHearts(Rank.aceLow,Suit.hearts),aceLowOfSpades(Rank.aceLow,Suit.spades),dueceOfClubs(Rank.deuce,Suit.clubs),dueceOfDiamonds(Rank.deuce,Suit.diamonds),dueceOfHearts(Rank.deuce,Suit.hearts),dueceOfSpades(Rank.deuce,Suit.spades),treyOfClubs(Rank.trey,Suit.clubs),treyOfDiamonds(Rank.trey,Suit.diamonds),treyOfHearts(Rank.trey,Suit.hearts),treyOfSpades(Rank.trey,Suit.spades),fourOfClubs(Rank.four,Suit.clubs),fourOfDiamonds(Rank.four,Suit.diamonds),fourOfHearts(Rank.four,Suit.hearts),fourOfSpades(Rank.four,Suit.spades),fiveOfClubs(Rank.five,Suit.clubs),fiveOfDiamonds(Rank.five,Suit.diamonds),fiveOfHearts(Rank.five,Suit.hearts),fiveOfSpades(Rank.five,Suit.spades),sixOfClubs(
                Rank.six,Suit.clubs),sixOfDiamonds(Rank.six,Suit.diamonds),sixOfHearts(Rank.six,Suit.hearts),sixOfSpades(Rank.six,Suit.spades),sevenOfClubs(Rank.seven,Suit.clubs),sevenOfDiamonds(Rank.seven,Suit.diamonds),sevenOfHearts(Rank.seven,Suit.hearts),sevenOfSpades(Rank.seven,Suit.spades),eightOfClubs(Rank.eight,Suit.clubs),eightOfDiamonds(Rank.eight,Suit.diamonds),eightOfHearts(Rank.eight,Suit.hearts),eightOfSpades(Rank.eight,Suit.spades),nineOfClubs(Rank.nine,Suit.clubs),nineOfDiamonds(Rank.nine,Suit.diamonds),nineOfHearts(Rank.nine,Suit.hearts),nineOfSpades(Rank.nine,Suit.spades),tenOfClubs(Rank.ten,Suit.clubs),tenOfDiamonds(Rank.ten,Suit.diamonds),tenOfHearts(Rank.ten,Suit.hearts),tenOfSpades(Rank.ten,Suit.spades),jackOfClubs(Rank.jack,Suit.clubs),jackOfDiamonds(Rank.jack,
                Suit.diamonds),jackOfHearts(Rank.jack,Suit.hearts),jackOfSpades(Rank.jack,Suit.spades),queenOfClubs(Rank.queen,Suit.clubs),queenOfDiamonds(Rank.queen,Suit.diamonds),queenOfHearts(Rank.queen,Suit.hearts),queenOfSpades(Rank.queen,Suit.spades),kingOfClubs(Rank.king,Suit.clubs),kingOfDiamonds(Rank.king,Suit.diamonds),kingOfHearts(Rank.king,Suit.hearts),kingOfSpades(Rank.king,Suit.spades),aceOfClubs(Rank.aceHigh,Suit.clubs),aceOfDiamonds(Rank.aceHigh,Suit.diamonds),aceOfHearts(Rank.aceHigh,Suit.hearts),aceOfSpades(Rank.aceHigh,Suit.spades);
        private Card(Rank rank,Suit suit) {
            this.rank=rank;
            this.suit=suit;
        }
        public Rank rank() {
            return rank;
        }
        public Suit suit() {
            return suit;
        }
        public String toString() {
            if(rank.equals(Rank.joker)||suit.equals(Suit.joker))
                return "Joker";
            else return rank+" of "+suit+'s';
        }
        public static String toString(final Card[] card) {
            String s=new String();
            for(int i=0;i<card.length;i++) {
                if(i>0)
                    s+=", ";
                s+=card[i].toCharacters();
            }
            return s;
        }
        public String toCharacters() {
            return ""+rank().toCharacter()+suit().toCharacter();
        }
        public boolean isNatural() {
            return rank!=Rank.joker&&suit!=Suit.joker;
        }
        public static Card instance(Rank rank,Suit suit) { // some hack for speed
            final int n=4*rank.ordinal()+suit.ordinal();
            // System.out.println(rank+" "+suit+" "+n);
            return element[4*rank.ordinal()+suit.ordinal()];
        }
        public static void replace(final Card[] cards,final int i,final Card card) {
            cards[i]=card;
        }
        static Card[] create(int standards,int jokers) {
            int cards=0;
            Card card[]=new Card[standards*52+jokers];
            for(int i=0;i<standards;i++)
                for(Suit suit:EnumSet.range(Suit.clubs,Suit.spades))
                    for(Rank rank:EnumSet.range(Rank.deuce,Rank.aceHigh))
                        card[cards++]=instance(rank,suit);
            for(int i=0;i<jokers;i++)
                card[cards++]=instance(Rank.joker,Suit.joker);
            return card;
        }
        private final Rank rank;
        private final Suit suit;
        private static final Card element[]={joker,joker,joker,joker,joker,aceLowOfClubs,aceLowOfDiamonds,aceLowOfHearts,aceLowOfSpades,dueceOfClubs,dueceOfDiamonds,dueceOfHearts,dueceOfSpades,treyOfClubs,treyOfDiamonds,treyOfHearts,treyOfSpades,fourOfClubs,fourOfDiamonds,fourOfHearts,fourOfSpades,fiveOfClubs,fiveOfDiamonds,fiveOfHearts,fiveOfSpades,sixOfClubs,sixOfDiamonds,sixOfHearts,sixOfSpades,sevenOfClubs,sevenOfDiamonds,sevenOfHearts,sevenOfSpades,eightOfClubs,eightOfDiamonds,eightOfHearts,eightOfSpades,nineOfClubs,nineOfDiamonds,nineOfHearts,nineOfSpades,tenOfClubs,tenOfDiamonds,tenOfHearts,tenOfSpades,jackOfClubs,jackOfDiamonds,jackOfHearts,jackOfSpades,queenOfClubs,queenOfDiamonds,queenOfHearts,queenOfSpades,kingOfClubs,kingOfDiamonds,kingOfHearts,kingOfSpades,aceOfClubs,
                aceOfDiamonds,aceOfHearts,aceOfSpades};
    }
    abstract class Cards {
        public Cards(final Card[] cards) {
            this.cards=cards;
        }
        public final Card card(int n) {
            return cards[n];
        }
        public boolean areSuited() {
            return areSuited(cards);
        }
        public boolean areNatural() {
            return areNatural(cards);
        }
        public String toCharacters() {
            String s=new String();
            for(Card c:cards)
                s+=c.toCharacters();
            return s;
        }
        public int size() {
            return cards.length;
        }
        public Card[] cards() {
            return cards;
        }
        protected void replace(int i,Card card) {
            Card.replace(cards,i,card);
        }
        public void shuffle() {
            final Random random=new Random();
            final int n=cards.length;
            Card temp;
            for(int i=n-1;i>0;i--) {
                int r=random.nextInt(i);
                temp=cards[i];
                cards[i]=cards[r];
                cards[r]=temp;
            }
        }
        public Rank[] ranks() {
            return Cards.ranks(cards);
        }
        public Suit[] suits() {
            return Cards.suits(cards);
        }
        public String toString() {
            return Card.toString(cards);
        }
        protected static Card[] toArray(final Card card1,final Card card2,final Card card3,final Card card4,final Card card5) {
            final Card card[]=new Card[5];
            card[0]=card1;
            card[1]=card2;
            card[2]=card3;
            card[3]=card4;
            card[4]=card5;
            return card;
        }
        static Card[] toArray(final Card card1,final Card card2,final Card card3,final Card card4,final Card card5,final Card card6,final Card card7) {
            final Card card[]=new Card[7];
            card[0]=card1;
            card[1]=card2;
            card[2]=card3;
            card[3]=card4;
            card[4]=card5;
            card[6]=card6;
            card[7]=card7;
            return card;
        }
        public static Suit[] suits(final Card[] card) {
            final int n=card.length;
            final Suit[] suits=new Suit[n];
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                suits[i]=card[i].suit();
            return suits;
        }
        public static boolean areSuited(final Card[] card) {
            final int n=card.length;
            for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
                if(card[i].suit()!=card[i+1].suit()) // may be null!
                    return false;
            return true;
        }
        public static boolean areNatural(final Card[] card) {
            for(Card c:card)
                if(!c.isNatural())
                    return false;
            return true;
        }
        public static Rank[] ranks(final Card[] card) {
            final Rank[] rank=new Rank[card.length];
            for(int i=0;i<card.length;i++)
                if(card[i]!=null)
                    rank[i]=card[i].rank();
                else throw new RuntimeException("card is null!");
            return rank;
        }
        public static final long f(final int n) { // factorial
            long i,p;
            if(n<=1)
                p=1;
            else for(p=n,i=2;i<=n-1;i++)
                p=p*i;
            return (p);
        }
        public static final int c(final int n,final int r) { // binomial coefficient
            long i,p;
            if(r<0||n<0||r>n)
                p=0;
            else if(r==0)
                p=1;
            else if(r>n-r)
                p=c(n,n-r);
            else {
                for(p=1,i=n;i>=n-r+1;i--)
                    p=p*i;
                p=p/f(r);
            }
            return (int)p;
        }
        public static List<int[]> permutations(int n) {
            final List<int[]> v=new ArrayList<int[]>();
            if(n<=1) {
                int[] a=new int[1];
                a[0]=0;
                v.add(a);
            } else {
                final List<int[]> v1=permutations(n-1);
                int nm1f=v1.size();
                for(int i=0;i<nm1f;i++) {
                    int[] a=(int[])v1.get(i);
                    for(int j=0;j<n;j++) { // copy a, inserting n at a2[j]
                        int[] a2=new int[n];
                        for(int k=0;k<j;k++)
                            a2[k]=a[k];
                        a2[j]=n-1;
                        for(int k=j;k<n-1;k++)
                            a2[k+1]=a[k];
                        v.add(a2);
                    }
                }
            }
            return v;
        }
        private final Card[] cards;
    }
    class Deck extends Cards {
        public Deck() {
            this(create(1,0));
        }
        public Deck(int standards,int jokers) {
            this(create(standards,jokers));
        }
        Deck(Card[] cards) {
            super(cards);
        }
        public final int stubLength() {
            return size()-nextCard;
        }
        public void shuffle() {
            super.shuffle();
            nextCard=0;
        }
        public final Card draw() {
            return card(nextCard++);
        }
        public void draw(Card[] cards) {
            for(int i=0;i<cards.length;i++)
                cards[i]=draw();
        }
        public final Card[] draw(final int n) {
            final Card[] cards=new Card[n];
            draw(cards);
            return cards;
        }
        public Card[] cards() {
            return super.cards();
        }
        public static Card[] create(int standards,int jokers) {
            int cards=0;
            Card card[]=new Card[standards*52+jokers];
            for(int i=0;i<standards;i++)
                for(Suit suit:EnumSet.range(Suit.clubs,Suit.spades))
                    for(Rank rank:EnumSet.range(Rank.deuce,Rank.aceHigh))
                        card[cards++]=Card.instance(rank,suit);
            for(int i=0;i<jokers;i++)
                card[cards++]=Card.instance(Rank.joker,Suit.joker);
            return card;
        }
        static boolean isDeckSuited(Cards c) { // suit order may be wrong for this
            Card[] cards=c.cards();
            for(int i=0;i<Math.min(cards.length,deck.cards().length);i++)
                if(cards[i]!=deck.cards()[i])
                    return false;
            return true;
        }
        static Deck deck=new Deck();
        private int nextCard;
    }
    public class Sample {
        public static void main(String[] arguments) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.asList(Rank.values()));
            System.out.println(Arrays.asList(Suit.values()));
            Deck deck=new Deck();
            System.out.println(Arrays.asList(deck.cards()));
            deck.shuffle();
            System.out.println(Arrays.asList(deck.cards()));
        }
    }
```